# Magento + Cloud Computing (AWS,GCP) problem

Tags: php, server-setup

I am trying to install Magento on Ubuntu 16.04 on a GCP and AWS server. For some reason it doesn't work http://35.166.35.15/

As you can see the css doesn't work well. Full permissions. Installed perfectly well. Locally on lamp stack it works fine. But for some reason it doesn't on the cloud. What would be a possible reason for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your url's are not rewritten to the index.php file (or other entry points like static.php). If you use an apache webserver, you have to install and activate the mod_rewrite module

For example:

```
http://...url.../customer/account/create
```

does not work but

```
http://...url.../index.php/customer/account/create
```

does work.

You can also deactivate url rewrites in the core config, but you have to find it in the database (core_config_data table) or be able to access your backend. Deactivating the setting would then make magento to add the `index.php` part to all generated url's

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mod_rewrite-for-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04